# Reducing number of lines per email to show more emails on a page

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, format

In Outlook 2016 can I reduce the inbox listing to one line per message as I am used to in Windows Live Mail.

Comment: Which version of Outlook are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the "Single" view:

Click the "View" tab, then click the "Change View" button and select "Single".

Here's a screenshot from Outlook 2010 but it's the same in Outlook 2013:

[image]